# Rails how to access a model across all controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a questions controller and a question model, and I want to access a particular question on a, say, static welcome page, how can I reference a particular question on an action not associated with the question controller? I'm having difficulty figuring out how to reference models everywhere, with a user I think this can be done with a cookie or something? But not sure about questions, I'm new to Rails so thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controllers and views can access any / all of your models.

The controller accesses models via various ActiveRecord APIs:

```
User.find(params[:user_id])
```

The view then accesses this data via instance variables:

```
# Controller sets instance var
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])

<%# View uses instance var %>
<h1><%= @user.first_name %></h1>
```

Read these Rails guides:

1. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
2. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand but...

All models are accessible from all controllers. You only need to get it (@question = Question.find(...))